# Implicit differentiation of trigonometric function $x\tan(y)=6-x^2$

Tags: trigonometry

I am asked to find the equation of the tangent and the normal to the curve $$x\tan(y)=6-x^2$$ at the point $(2,\pi/4)$.
Rearrange to $$x\tan(y)+x^2-6=0$$
By product rule $$\frac{d}{dy}( x\tan(y)) = \tan(y)$$ so $$\frac{d}{dx} x\tan(y)+x^2-6 = \tan(y)-2x$$
At $(2,\pi/4)$ $$\frac {dy}{dx}=\tan(\pi/4)-2\cdot2
\tan(\pi/4)=1$$ therefore at $(2,\pi/4)$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=5.$
However, the book answer for this question is that the equation of the tangent is
$4y+5x=\pi+10$ and that for normal is $20y-16x=5\pi-32.$
The book answer means that at $(2,\pi/4)$, $dy/dx=-5/4$, not $5$.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't differentiated the equation of curve properly. We are differentiating with respect to x. So, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left( x\tan(y)\right)+\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)+\frac{d}{dx}(-6)=0$$ Hence, by applying product rule, $$\left(x\frac{d}{dx}(\tan(y))+\tan(y)\frac{d}{dx}(x)\right)+2x+0=0$$ $$x\sec^2(y)\frac{dy}{dx}+\tan(y)+2x=0$$

Now, put  $x=2$, and $y=\pi/4$. You will get the required answer.